# Python Django length of form field input is 1 even when it's empty

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm working on a project using Python(3.6) and Django(2.1) in which I need to implement the search functionality. I have two fields for search `what` and `where`.
The user can enter multiple values for both of these fields and separate them by a `,`, then I need to check the length of both fields after splitting it by `,`. When a field is empty it's length should be `0` but in my case, it shows that the length is `1` even when the field is empty.

Here's my code:
**From forms.py:**

```
class FetchDataForm(forms.Form):
    what = forms.CharField(max_length=256, required=True)
    where = forms.CharField(max_length=256, required=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('what', 'where')
```

**From templates/search.html:**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'udata:fetch-data' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="font-size: x-large">What:</label>
                    <br><span class="help"
                              style="font-size: smaller; padding-top: 0%;"> keywords, or company</span>
                    {% if dd.what %}
                        <input type="text" name="what" value="{{ dd.what }}" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
                    {% else %}
                        <input type="text" name="what" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" style="font-size: x-large">Where:</label>
                    <br><span class="help"
                              style="font-size: smaller; padding-top: 0%;">City, State or Zip code</span>
                    {% if dd.where %}
                        <input type="text" name="where" value="{{ dd.where }}" class="form-control"
                               id="inputPassword4">
                    {% else %}
                        <input type="text" name="where" value="" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4">
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <label for="inputPassword4">&nbsp;</label>
                <br><span class="help" style="font-size: smaller;"> &nbsp;</span>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="margin-top:10%">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

And 
**From views.py:**

```
what = form.cleaned_data['what']
where = form.cleaned_data['where']
get_len_what = len(what.split(','))
get_len_where = len(where.split(','))
print('What len is {}'.format(get_len_what))
print('where len is {}'.format(get_len_where))
```

It prints out the length as `1` even when the fields are empty.
What's can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution:

```
what = form.cleaned_data['what']
if ',' not in what and len(what) > 0:
    get_len_what = len(what.split(','))
elif ',' in what and len(what) > 0:
    get_len_what = len(what.split(','))
else:
    get_len_what = len(what.split(',')) - 1
```

And, we can implement same for another one, which is `where`.